# Using frame through code for a queue

Tags: delphi, frames

So I have a program that runs a simulation

When you select the model, it opens a screen which lets you select "Run the Model", which opens another screen in which you can press the start button

I want to make a queue so that the user could select multiple models and the program would run through these screens without user input

So, I'm calling a frame like this:

```
ProgForm := TProgressForm.Create(Self, FModItem);
Self.Visible := False;
try
 ProgForm.ShowModal;
```

Now, I can get the program to run by adding a line at the end of Create to run the simulation, but the problem is that it doesn't show the frame until the end of the simulation (since the Create constructor isn't finished until the run function I called is finished)

I'm not sure what to do, since if I don't add anything in the Create function I'm calling, there doesn't seem to be any other way to call any function automatically, but if I do something in Create, the frame isn't displayed until Create is finished

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest reading:

http://delphi.about.com/od/formsdialogs/a/delphiformlife.htm

You can use the form's `OnShow` event to do stuff before the form is fully drawn on the screen.
`OnActivate` is usually the best place to do stuff when the form is drawn.

**BTW**
you say Frame, but in your code it says `TProgressForm` so I'm guessing you mean `Form` with a `Frame` inside.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I was looking for, OnActivate works perfectly

Comment: OnActivate is also called if there are two or more forms in the same "modal stack" level and the user switches between those forms. So be careful when using OnActivate as "OnAfterShow".